# ZFS3 Lost Resilience. Is Read-only Safer than Letting Users Carry on Writing Files?

Tags: zfs, best-practices

Three lovely ST8000NM0075 Seagates drives supplied by Dell, all suddenly failed in a RaidZ3, that's now four within 3 years and 4 months.

I didn't anticipate this and only have one spare to plug in. Feels dangerous.

I would like to change the pool to read-only while the semi-offiste differential backup completes.

My reasoning is that the pool should be more stable if it's static, and I disable autosnapshots temporarily.

My concern is that resilvering will take days, and the multiuser system is always busy.

Is this reasonable or justifiable? Does it in fact hedge a little bit of caution?

The downside of not going read-only is yet another discontinuity of business within the same month that falls on me. I'm not sure if the impressions will be reparable, but that's fine if it's the wise decision to go read-only and repair the pool...after the backup.

Would taking the pool completely offline be even more safe that leaving it read-only?

```
$ dev/disk# zpool status -v
  pool: darkpool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
    invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
    functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub in progress since Fri Nov  8 04:52:09 2019
    1004G scanned out of 47.5T at 81.4M/s, 166h22m to go
    0B repaired, 2.06% done
config:

    NAME                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    darkpool                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz3-0                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581aafb    ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b61b    ONLINE       0     0     0
        783034318520267027        FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sdm1
        7369503050985789936       FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sdj1
        wwn-0x5000c5008581b953    ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581bdf7    ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c50085825ec7    ONLINE       0     0     0
        11744243917579175290      FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sdg1
        wwn-0x5000c5008581e423    ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c5008581fd3f    ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c50085820b93    ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500858211b3    ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000cca267ab0de4    ONLINE       0     0     0
        spare-13                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
          11992420879588183985    FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:10:0-part1
          wwn-0x5000c500858252ef  ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      wwn-0x5000c500858252ef      INUSE     currently in use
```

---

I have one more unboxed drive, not to be confused with the spare that's currently in use replacing another failed disk.

---

No, I was not involved in the planning of this setup.

Comment: Wait, you have a RAIDZ3 comprised of 4 disks?

Comment: @ewwshite No, I have this mess

Comment: @ewwhite So sorry for the delays in payment. You were very wonderful to work with. Please forgive the constant delays. I truly thought you were paid months before I got an email from your assistant.